# Can't mount / format USB stick

Tags: usb, mount, ntfs

I have formatted USB stick and now I can't mount it.

Command `sudo fdisk -l` outputs this (shortened to only show info about *sdc* and *sdc1*):

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 8075 MB, 8075120640 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 7701 cylinders, total 15771720 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x22fb6a74

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *           0      407551      203776   17  Hidden HPFS/NTFS

Disk /dev/sdc1: 208 MB, 208666624 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 199 cylinders, total 407552 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x22fb6a74

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1p1   *           0      407551      203776   17  Hidden HPFS/NTFS
```

If I try to mount sdc1 with `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdc1 /mnt` the output is:

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

EDIT:

Output of command `sudo lsblk -f` is:

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL MOUNTPOINT
sda                 
├─sda1 ext4         /
├─sda2              
└─sda5 swap         [SWAP]
sdb                 
├─sdb1              
└─sdb5 ext4         /media/disc_d
sdc                 
└─sdc1              
sr0
```

Comment: Try `sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt -o uid=1000` , without the -t options. Let me know if works, i will convert it to answer

Comment: unplug it and plug it back in to automount

Comment: Result of Serg's command is: `mount: you must specify the filesystem type`

Comment: Are you sure, that `sdc1` actually contains a NTFS? Please verify with `sudo blkid /dev/sdc1` or more generally `sudo lsblk -f`.

Comment: what is the result for dpkg -l | grep ntfs | grep ii # if there is no output, then you need to install

Comment: Result of dpkg is `ii  ntfs-3g                                               1:2013.1.13AR.1-2ubuntu2                            amd64        read/write NTFS driver for FUSE`

Comment: first run sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g .. Format the disk you wish to mount.. then instead of sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdc1 /mnt try (1) sudo mkdir /test (2)sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdc1 /test

Comment: Aravinda result is `NTFS signature is missing.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You formatted the USB disk wrongly: it has a *Hidden* HPFS/NTFS partition.

1. Open `gparted`
2. Navigate to the correct disk in the upper right corner:

[image]

3. Go to `device` and choose `create partition table` and choose `msdos`
4. Right-click the large empty square in the middle:

[image]

and choose "format to" and take FAT32

### Done!  ;-)